# How do I test the accessibility of my Firefox extension's toolbar button (and attached popup)?

Tags: accessibility, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing a Firefox (web)extension.  I have a `browser_action` in my `manifest.json`, with a `default_popup`.  I want my extension to be accessible by all users, including those with vision impairment.

So I'd like to, as I change and develop things, test what it's like to (for example) interact with this feature, using only the keyboard.  How do I do this?  How do I focus and thus "click" the toolbar button, without a mouse?

Ideally, without actually running special screen reader software every time.

Answer (score 0):

> So I'd like to, as I change and develop things, test what it's like to
>   (for example) interact with this feature, using only the keyboard. How
>   do I do this? How do I focus and thus "click" the toolbar button,
>   without a mouse?

You can use [commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/commands) to set a keyboard shortcut.

> *_execute_browser_action*: works like a click on the extension's browser action

You may also add [commands.update()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/commands/update) (Firefox 60+) API to let users change that keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for considering accessibility.  Just to clarify, because I don't think you meant this, but you can do keyboard testing without a screen reader.  Just don't use your mouse :-)  Seriously.

In my current firefox, I have an address bar, the search field, then a bunch of plugins on a toolbar.

[image: toolbar]

On a PC (should be similar for a Mac, but <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>):

- I can move my keyboard focus to the address bar with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
- I can move my keyboard focus to the search field with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>)

Interestingly enough, I could not get my focus on the toolbar.  I could have sworn I could tab from the address field, to the search field, to the toolbar, but it's not working now.

If you can get your focus there, then you should be able to use the left/right arrows to move between tools and then <kbd>space</kbd>/<kbd>enter</kbd> to select the tool.

If you want to play with a screen reader, [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) is free.

Comment: "Interestingly enough, I could not get my focus on the toolbar."  This is literally my entire question.

Comment: I’ll keep poking around. I know I’ve done it before but perhaps a FF update took that option away. I specialize in accessibility so use the keyboard and screen reader all the time.